# Закрыть форму полностью при этом таймер не должен обнуляться и не начинать с нуля winforms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Тут такое дело. Есть таймер он находится в UserControl. Этот UserControl создается в втором форме через foreach. Во вторую форму попадаю через первый форму, в первом форме ввожу пароль чтоб зайтди во вторую форму. Надо мне так сделать при включение таймер таймер и при случайного первой закрытия формы таймер должен работать. Можете мне какой нибудь совет дать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Сделать таймер глобальный, не в форме, а в неком классе. Далее инициализировать и передавать ссылку на него куда надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ок, спасибо.

Comment: Как вам выше ответили, создавайте таймер на уровне приложения, а не на уровне формы.